# prove that the Dimension for set of all linear mappings $L:V \to W$ is equal to $\dim V \times \dim W$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I wish to prove that the dimension for the set of all linear mappings $L:V \to W$ is equal to $\dim V \times \dim W$. I know that any general linear mapping can be represented as a matrix, so intuitevely it makes sense that the dimension should be $\dim V \times \dim W$ but I cannot find a way to prove this mathematically

Comment: Try constructing an isomorphism from $\mathcal L(V,W)\to M_{m\times n}(\mathcal F),$ given that $\dim(V)=n, \dim(W)=m$.

Comment: In general, if $V$ is finite-dimensional (regardless of whether $W$ is finite-dimensional), the equality $$\dim\big(\text{Hom}(V,W)\big)=\dim(V)\,\dim(W)$$ holds always.  However, the equality is false when $V$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @IsanaYashiro would the linear mapping T that takes a linear mapping from L and maps it to its standard matrix work as an isomorphism?

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt: Yes, since $\Phi_{\beta\to\gamma}(T):=[T]_\beta^\gamma$ is isomorphism with any choices of $\beta,\gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m=\dim V, n=\dim W$. Any linear map $$L:\Bbb R^m\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$$ may be represented as an $n\times m$-matrix $$\mathbf{L}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&\dots&a_{1,m}\\a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&\dots&a_{2,m}\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\a_{n,1}&a_{n,2}&\dots&a_{n,m}\end{pmatrix}$$

How many different such $\mathbf{L}$ can you make?